# counting duplicates in c++

Tags: c++, duplicates

Let's say I have an array of ints {100, 80, 90, 100, 80, 60}

so I want to count those duplicates and save those counter for later.
because each duplicate number should be divided by counter

like 100 is duplicated 2 times so they should be 50 each.

to find duplicates, I used sort.

```
std::sort(array, array + number);
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  if(array[i] == array[i+1])
    counter++;
}
```

and I've tried to make counter array to save them on each num of array. but it didn't work. please give me some better idea.

Comment: As written, the index in `array[i+1]` runs off the top of the array. Change the loop to only run until `i < number - 1`. That won't fix the counting, since the code counts all the occurrences of duplicates and not each duplicate separately.

Comment: You want to count each duplicate (e.g. 100: 2 and 80:2) ?

Comment: the most classic solution to these problem is a binary tree, if the number are random enough, otherwise a balanced binary tree. Other an hash table.

Comment: yes so I want to change each 100 into 50 @Christophe

Comment: Are the `int`s in the array constrained in a range? I mean, as an example, you don't know how much and what are there, but you know that they are in the range `[N,M[`. Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Approach 1**

The easiest way, is not to sort your array, and increment elements of a map:

```
unordered_map<int, size_t> count;  // holds count of each encountered number 
for (int i=0; i<number; i++)        
    count[array[i]]++;             // magic !
```

You can then process the content of the map:

```
for (auto &e:count)                // display the result 
    cout << e.first <<" : "<<e.second<< "-> "<<e.first/e.second<<endl;
```

If needed, filter out the non duplicates by rerasing them from the map or ignoring it during the processing.

**Approach 2**

If you're not allowed to use maps, then you have to elaborate your counting loop, in order to restart counting for each new number, and being able to process consecutive dups also if more than two:

```
...
for(int i = 0; i < number; i+=counter) {
    for (counter=1; i+counter<number && array[i+counter]==array[i]; ) 
        counter++;       // count consecutives dups
    if (counter>1) {     // if more than one, process the dups.  
        cout << "dup: " << array[i] << " "<<counter<<endl;   
    }
}
```

If you need to store the pairs to process them in asecond step, you need to store a pair (preferably in a vector, but if needed in an array):

```
pair<int, size_t> result[number];  // a vector would be preferable
int nres=0; 
... 
    if (counter>1) {     // if more than one, process the dups.  
        // cout << "dup: " << array[i] << " "<<counter<<endl; 
        result[nres++] = make_pair(array[i], counter);  
    }
...
```

[Online demo for both approaches](http://ideone.com/RWZ8wH)

Comment: Omggg thanks a lot!! I've been struggling with this and I didn't know how to use map but this is really helpful to me :)

Comment: sorry for asking again. But I've been thinking and I couldn't figure out how to divide each duplicates by counter of duplicates so e.g. {10,10,6,6,7} => {5,5,3,3,7} without using map?

Comment: If you can use the map, go for it without questions. If you're not allowed (homework?) then you ban store a pair in a vector (see above), or store in a vector of a struct containing the numer and the count (i.e a handcrafted pair), or use 2 vectors: one for the found duplicates and one for the corresponding count.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::map<int,int>` or `std::unordered_map` for counting the occurences.

Then iterate over the map and replace each value by the key divided by the original value (counter).

Finally go through the original array and replace each number by its mapped value.

If you use a `std::unordered_map` the algorithm is O(n). Your original one is O(n log n) because sorting is involved.

Comment: but the thing is those numbers are in struct. Can I use map with struct?

Comment: @Hmmmmm: You could use a map of structs but I think it makes more sense just to extract the integers from the structs.

Comment: @Hmmmmm: The map doesn't need to contain the struct - just the integers.  When you go though the array the first time, you pull the integers out ( `counter[ array[i].int_member ] ++;`).  When you go through the second time, you just update the member: `array[i].int_member = counter_map[ array[i].int_member ];`)

Comment: @Hmmmmm or you could specialize `std::hash` for your struct and implement `operator==` of your struct to `std::unordered_map` work as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the array numbers directly, you may proceed like this:

```
for (int i = 0, counter = 1; i < number; i++) {
    if (array[i] == array[i + 1])
        counter++;
    else { //when finished counting duplicates
        for (int j = counter; j > 0; j--) //adjustment for subscripts
            array[i - j + 1] /= counter; //change the values stored in array
        counter = 1;//reinitialize array to 1
    }
}
```

Your sorted values stored in the array will come out already divided once by their corresponding counters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is algo to replace elements in place if you are allowed to modify sequence:

```
const auto begin = std::begin( data );
const auto end = std::end( data );
std::sort( begin, end );
for( auto it = begin; it != end; ) {
    auto next = std::upper_bound( std::next( it ), end, *it );
    auto newval = *it / std::distance( it, next );
    std::fill( it, next, newval );
    it = next;
}
```

demo on [ideone](http://ideone.com/0qC5jN)

PS modified to make it compile with array as well.

Comment: those numbers are in struct. How do I access to struct member?

Comment: @Hmmmmm Pretty easy. You create new question where you  provide proper information.