# Finding recurrence of array elements in the array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Recently, I started learning C++. I landed on this problem about finding average, highest and lowest scores, number of absent student, and which marks are repeated.

The average, lowest and highest scores, and number of absent student is working as intended. However, the repeated marks isn't working as intended.

The problematic Case is Case number 5.

It works to some extent but when I give input (1,2,1,2,3 alternate input) and
(1,2,1,2,1) it ignores the one of the number/prints some number again.
I don't know what to do since my knowledge is limited. Is there any solution to this program the way it is?

I tried to eliminate it but then normal(not alternate inputs) aren't working properly.

Could you also provide an alternative way that I can understand?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Marks[5], i, high, low, menu;
    int absent, extra=0, recurr, rcount=0, z;
    int hexa=0,seca ,octa=0;

    float average, sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter no of mark:";
        cin>>Marks[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        if(Marks[i]!=-1)
        {
            sum=sum+Marks[i];
            extra++;
        }

    cout<<"Choose your operation you want to perform";
    cout<<" \n 1.Average marks of the class \n 2.Highest Scores in Class \n 3.Lowest score in class\n 4.No of absent student\n 5.No of recurring element";

    cin>>menu;
    average=sum/extra;
    switch(menu)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Average="<<average;
            break;
        case 2:
            high=Marks[0];

            for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                if(high<=Marks[i])
                    high=Marks[i];

            cout<<"Highest marks= "<<"\n"<<high;
            break;
        case 3:
            if(Marks[i]!=-1)
            {
                low=Marks[0];

                for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                    if(Marks[i]!=-1)
                        if(low>=Marks[i])
                            low=Marks[i];

                cout<<"Lowest Marks="<<"\n"<<low;
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            absent=Marks[0];

            for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                if(Marks[i]==-1) //if -1 is entered it is counted as absent
                    cout<<"Student no\t"<<i+1<<"\twas abesnt for the exam";

            break;
        case 5:
            //Here is the function that is giving me problem
            for(seca=0; seca<5; seca++)
            {
                recurr=Marks[hexa];
                for(i=0; i<5; i++)
                    if(recurr==Marks[i])
                    {
                        rcount++;
                        z=rcount;
                        if(z==2)
                            octa++;

                        if(octa>2)
                            octa--;

                    }

                hexa++;

                if(z<2)
                    cout<<"Number "<<recurr<<"is repeated "<<z<<" times\n";

                if((octa>1)&&(octa<5))
                {
                    cout<<"Number "<<recurr<<"is repeated "<<z<<" times\n";
                    octa=0;
                }
                rcount=0;
            }
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Choose a valid option!!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should learn to use containers and algorithm functions.  Your task could be basically done in  around 10 lines or less if you used those aspects of C++.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This is very hard to read.

Comment: okay, Sorry about that .. Since I am beginner I didn't care about indentation at all.I will try to fix at asap.

Comment: I would argue that things like indentation should be towards the highest of your priorities as a beginner. It keeps things organized, and the last thing you want as a beginner is your own code to confuse you. (any athlete will tell you to focus on form first. Coding is no different)

Comment: Did a very quick pass over it, but you may still want to fix it up for consistency as I wasn't sure what style you wanted.

Comment: @DrC Thank you so much for that , I have tried to to make it more readable.@Borgleader

Comment: Do things as separate tasks. Getting the inputs is a task. Compute something is a task. Break things up into managable pieces and test each piece. Do you know how to make functions yet?

Comment: @KennyOstrom No I don't, sorry.

Comment: Tactical note: If case 5 is causing you trouble, build a small program that does nothing but case 5 and test the snot out of that program until you find the problem.  The rest is just a distraction unless some mistake in a previous cases breaks the program in such a way that the error only becomes visible in case 5. Either way, isolating case 5 will quickly let you know.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah .. I guess . I don't think previous case will give any problem. But yeah it is sure distracting.

Comment: @JeJo Intention ? I dont get it neither the code in link too :(.

Comment: @ShubhamWagh better stick to what user4581301 mentioned.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676779/counting-duplicates-in-c

Comment: I have taken your code and ripped out everything that is not required to demonstrate the bug. Around here this is what we call a [mcve] (MCVE). I have also added a few extra print statements to display what is happening. When you don't know what is happening, gather more information be it through debug statements or [the debugging software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that ships with every development environment worth using. I have fixed nothing, but hopefully being able to see the extra output will show you what went wrong. https://ideone.com/2ckTeZ

Comment: A note. The above isn't really a proper MCVE. The real beauty of a true MCVE is that it is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug. This makes finding the bug easy because it's the only thing left. It may remain hard to understand, but knowing where it is is usually half the battle. Yo Joe. Most of the time you don't need the full MCVE. When you get part way there, the bug has already revealed itself and you can fix it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for that but I had already noted 4 pages full of output and input to identify the problem , I know where it is going wrong but I can't fix it , if I try to fix it then normal input isn't working properly. But thanks!

Comment: The basic problems are you rescan numbers you've already checked, so in 1 2 1 2 1, you check 1 for repetition three times and 2 twice, so you get redundant outputs, and `if (octa > 2)
                {
                    octa--;
                }` guarantees that `octa` will never exceed 1. That means `if((octa>1)&&(octa<5))` will never be entered. Nothing will be printed and octa will never be reset.

Comment: Please enclose all blocks in { }. Even if it is just a single line! It will make the code easier to read and less error prone. Because every block/scope is directly visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, you should first sort it first and then you shall find it easy to count occurrences. As you are new to C++ I would suggest a sorting technique called Bubble Sort this will be easy for you :

```
for(i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<(n-i-1); j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
        {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Now after sorting just count the occurrences if you still find some error or doubt, please reply or if you don't get the method I will explain it further :)

Comment: Please explain more , I am not able to get it.

Comment: after applying the given code your input i.e., [1,2,1,2,1] will convert into [1,1,1,2,2]

Comment: after applying the given code your input i.e., [1,2,1,2,1] will convert into [1,1,1,2,2] now count the number of occurences aplying condition 'if(marks[i] == marks[i+1]) count++ //set the initial value of count to 1' as your condition will get false print your statement and set the count again to 1 you will definately get your desired output