# Why is the for loop running 6 iterations?

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help understanding the logic of why the `for` loop runs 6 times. Shouldn't the loop stop at `i = 4, j = 5`?

```
public static boolean methodName(int[] hand)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < hand.length; j++) {
            if (hand[i] == hand[j] && j != i) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }
    }
    if (counter == 4) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end method
```

I inserted that line, `System.out.println(counter)` to see how many iterations the loop does.

The output is below:

```
Enter five ints.
Input 1: 2
Input 2: 2
Input 3: 2
Input 4: 2
Input 5: 3
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Have you thought about adding a `println(i)` and `println(j)` to see how those values change?

Comment: What's the length of `hand`? What output are you expecting? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: length if hand is 5.

Comment: you have `&& j != i` but that will always happen because j=i+1 and above

Comment: @omajid the values of "i" stays at the same value twice before incrementing. That is the part I don't quite udnerstand and need help comprehending.

Comment: You're not outputting the value of `i`; instead you're outputting `counter`. `i++` guarantees that the value of `i` is _not_ the same during the iteration.

Comment: It seems like this code is looking for a 4 of a kind from poker.  I would suggest reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676779/counting-duplicates-in-c which suggest using std::map.

Comment: @Mike It is not. It is very similar though. Just trying to understand how nested for loops works.

Answer (score 1):

The outer `for` loop (`for(int i = 0; i < hand.length-1; i++) {`) will run `i-1` times (With the length being `i`). Then the inner loop will run `n-i` on each iteration of the outer `for` loop. So it is running much more than six times. The reason why it only seams like it is running six times is that the condition that prints out `counter` only occurs six times. If you add in a `println()` you will see that with the length of 5 it runs 10 times:

```
int numOfLoops = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hand.length-1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < hand.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(++numOfLoops);

        if (hand[i] == hand[j] && j != i) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

***Output: (Ignoring the output of `counter`)***

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. This puts me on the right track.

Comment: But why is "i" not being incremented? It's checking i against every j.

Comment: @mchlvncntry What do you mean? What makes you say that `i` is not being incremented?

Comment: After the first iteration of both for loops, shouldn't i be equal to 1 and j equal to 2? Because i still at 0, while j is 1, 2, and 3 after 4 iterations.

Comment: @mchlvncntry `i` will get incremented after each iteration through the loop, so depending on where you place your `println()` it might print `i` as zero. (Because the print line will happen before `i` gets incremented)

Comment: But why does it run at least 6 times? In this case 10?

Comment: @mchlvncntry Because on every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will run multiple times

Answer (score 0):

It goes up to six, because for each value of i, it goes through every value of j that is greater than i.

So the six entries are:

1. i = 0, j = 1
2. i = 0, j = 2
3. i = 0, j = 3
4. i = 1, j = 2
5. i = 1, j = 3
6. i = 2, j = 3

I'm guessing you want an extra check to ensure that no match gets counted twice.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am trying to understand how this for loop works prior to fixing it to achieve what is desired.

Comment: Right. For loops don't run 1-2-1-2. In this case, your first for loop (the outer loop) will run 5 times. But every time it runs, the second loop (the inner one) will run 5-(i+1) times. So the first loop will run, where i=0, and the inner loop will run 4 times. Then the first loop will run again, where i=1. The second loop will run three times. etc. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
I=0,J=1, 2=2 counter = 1  
I=0,J=2 2=2 counter = 2  
I=0,J=3 2=2 counter = 3  
I=0,J=4 2<>3 counter = 3 no print  
I=1,J=2, 2=2 counter = 4  
I=1,J=3, 2=2 counter = 5  
I=1,J=4, 2<>3 counter = 5 no print  
I=2,J=3, 2=2 counter = 6  
I=3,J=4, 2<>3 counter = 6 no print
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for this. I am trying to understand how this for loop works prior to fixing it to achieve what is desired.