# repeating elements in a given array

Tags: c++, arrays

there is a question to find the number of times an element in an array is repeating.
example:  {12 , 25 , 43 ,25 , 43}. 
Output:

```
12 occurs 1 time
25 occurs 2 times
43 occurs 2 times
```

But I'm getting output:

```
12 occurs 1 time
25 occurs 2 times
43 occurs 2 times
25 occurs 2 times
43 occurs 2 times
```

The code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a=1000;
    int index[a];
    for(int i=0; i<a ; i++){
        index[i]=0;
    }

    int n;
    cout<<"Size of Array : ";
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        if(index[arr[i]]>=0){
            index[arr[i]]+=1;
        }
    }
    int rep[n];
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        rep[i]=index[arr[i]];
    }
   

    cout<<  "The frequency of all elements of an array :"<<endl;


    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        if(index[arr[i]]>0){
            cout<<arr[i]<<" occurs "<<index[arr[i]]<<"times";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I got:
[image]

How do I avoid printing same element twice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676779/counting-duplicates-in-c

Comment: This becomes a lot simpler if you can sort the array (or a copy of it) first.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you are allowed to use `std::map<int, int>`.  The first parameter is the number (key) and the second is the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, a `std::map` would be the data structure to use:

```
#include <map>
//...
std::map<int, int> frequencies;  
//...
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
{
    frequencies[arr[i]]++;
}
//...
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator iter(frequencies.begin());
for (; iter != frequencies.end(); ++iter)
{
  std::cout << iter->first << ": " << iter->second << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the index array and print whenever the value is non zero:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  if (index[i] != 0) {
    std::cout << i << " occurs " << index[i] << " times.\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, this approach is not fully dynamic. It will only work if the values you enter inside the array are less than the size of the array. So, if let us say the size of the array is 5 and you enter one element in array 7, this code will not work properly.

Nevertheless, if this issue is not a problem, here is the code you might want to write modifying the approach you took initially:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a=1000;
    int index[a];
    for(int i=0; i<a ; i++){
        index[i]=0;
    }

    int n;
    cout<<"Size of Array : ";
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n ; i++){
        if(index[arr[i]]>=0){
            index[arr[i]]+=1;
        }
    }

    cout<<  "The frequency of all elements of an array :"<<endl;

    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        if(index[i]>0){
            cout<<i <<" occurs "<<index[i]<<" times";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```